# How to determine if a triangle can be drawn with the given points.

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

Given $3$ points
$$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3),$$ how does one determine whether they are vertices of a triangle?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: The triangle inequality deals with lengths, points.

Comment: If the points are given,you can always find the distance between them.

Comment: Have you ever tried to draw a triangle, given three points in the plane?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter its to determine with a program that handles larger numbers, that ain't possible to draw by myself.

Comment: @GTXOC: Think again. To solve this problem by calculating the side lengths and then using the triangle inequality would be absurd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: Find area of triangle formed by 3 points. if not zero they can form triangle.

2: Find line equation of 2 vertices and check if the 3rd vertices is present on this line. if not they can form triangle. Similarly Find the slope of the line joining points A and B,then find the slope of the line joining A and C.If they are same,then you can't draw a triangle.(@rah4927)

Comment: The second way can also be rephrased as follows:Find the slope of the line joining points A and B,then find the slope of the line joining A and C.If they are same,then you can't draw a triangle.Otherwise,you can.

Answer (score 4):

The area of a triangle is given by the formula $$|\frac12 det(\vec{AB}, \vec{AC})|$$

Let $$\vec{A}=(x_1,y_1), \vec{B}=(x_2,y_2), \vec{C}=(x_3, y_3)$$

Then $$\vec{AB}=(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1), \vec{AC}=(x_3-x_1,y_3-y_1)$$

Then it must hold that $$|  
(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(y_2-y_1)(x_3-x_1)| \neq 0$$

Answer (score -3):

A triangle can be drawn with three points iff these three points are three different points.

EDIT: in order to be more precise in the core of my answer, and not in comment: three distincts colinear points form a degenerate triangle, but a triangle nonetheless. It is a geometric figure with three angles (they can be calculated, and not in the case where there are only one or two disctinct points) and their sum is 180°...

Comment: They might be collinear.

Comment: what if the three different points are on a line?

Comment: For me this is still a triangle (a flat one), since you have three angles you can define and measure. If you have two point identical, or three, you can't define the three angles...

Comment: I am NOK with the downvotes. A degenerate triangle is a triangle... Or else explain to me why not...

Comment: @Martigan: someone asking a question as basic as the OP's won't surely understand "degenerate triangles": in high school, a triangle is a plane figure obtained by joining three non-collinear points by straight line segments. And even following your reasoning: the three points do *not* have to be different, as the degenerate triangle's vertices could aslo be degenerate, or collapsed into two or only one point representing the three vertices. Too much for such a basic question, imo.